# Use only the woocommerce product category for posts and products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories, posts

In woocommerce/includes/class-wc-post-types.php
Line 51 and 85, I change:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_product_cat', array( 'product' ) ),
```

to

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_taxonomy_objects_product_cat', array( 'product', 'post' ) ),
```

and the output is below in the image.

It's not updating when I want to assign the product category to post. Also the posts are still using the default WP post category taxonomy, when I check the product category and push the update button.

[image: the output of the above changes in the code]

Comment: **Do not modify core files.** There's a reason `add_filter` exists. Also, you can assign multiple taxonomies (e.g. categories) to post types, so registering the product category taxonomy for Posts will not remove/deactivate the default Post category taxonomy. That's a separate process.

Comment: thanks alot for editing the question Respected disinfor sir .I dont want to remove or deactivated the default post category taxonomy i will uncheck the post category and checked the product category but its not working

Comment: What do you mean by "no working?" On the front end? Is it not saving the Product Category to the Post? If you save, does the box remain checked? Need some more information.

Comment: Yes exactly it's not saving the product category when I click the update button and yes the post category remains checked to uncategorized